# Is Javascript good for memory changing?

Tags: javascript, memory

First off, I wanna make sure that memory is same stuff as the address' given in CheatEngine. If its not, please reply telling me and ignore the rest of this thread.

I'm really only good at Lua and Javascript. But something I really want to do is change memory values. Lua is out of the question so i'm curious about javascript. Is it any good with changing the values of memory?

Also, what languages should I learn so I can change memory values?

Comment: You can't access the memory of other processes in Javascript. I guess C++ would be a good choice for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure CheatEngine does read the memory addresses that belong to a certain process. Javascript does not allow you to do this properly.

If you want to do this the right way, languages that are very low level are the way to go. Examples of these languages are C and C++. Learning these languages is not a very easy task however. Though if you just want to read out memory you should not have a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a standalone trainer/cheat, you can save to .exe from CheatEngine: **Save as... > CE Standalone trainer**.

Also, why is Lua out of question? It's the script language used by CE, you can easily generate a script containing the "adress meddling" and run that in any Lua engine. Or even better, you can make CE generate your entire trainer (you can custom the UI): **File > Generate generic trainer lua script from table**.